# Problemas com eventos em elementos criados dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Minha intenção é:**

Uma listagem onde é possível adicionar `<div>` e apagar as divs adicionadas com um "botão" inserido em cada `div`.

A página já vem com umas `divs` inseridas fixas que são iguais as que serão adicionadas.

A questão é, nas `divs` que já estão na página, o botão de apaga-las funciona corretamente, agora as `divs` que são inseridas com `prepend` não são apagadas. Já chequei a função do `remove()` e todas as `divs` tanto as fixas quanto as adicionadas tem a mesma classe. Enfim...

`list-mode` é a `div` que engloba todas essas `divs` no html, `.img_des_row` é a `div` que deve ser repetida e apagada...Relembrando: a adição está funcionando corretamente!

JavaScript:

```js
$("#bt-adicionar-imagens").click(function() {
    $(".list-mode").prepend("< div class='img_des_row col-xs-12'>< div class='col-xs-8 no-pad-left'>< div class='description_img'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do elusmod tempor.< /div>< /div>< div class='col-xs-2'><div class='pull-right margin-top_20 dropdown'><a href='#' class='icon-dwn-med pull-left margin_l_r_5'>< /a>< a href='#' class='icon-edit-med pull-left margin_l_r_5 dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>< /a>< div class='dropdown-menu alt-color-scheme left pad'>< /div>< a href='#' class='icon-trash-med pull-left margin_l_r_5'>< /a>< /div>< /div>< /div>");
});

$('.img_des_row .icon-trash-med').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".img_des_row").remove();
});
```

Comment: Se puder criar um [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) (e postar também seu html aqui na pergunta), com uma representação de seu problema real, com o seu html e seu JS, para podermos tentar lhe ajudar, e também sua pergunta é pouco confusa, tente reler e tentar melhora-la. E de uma olha nos [markdown aqui do site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help), formatei seu código e um pouco de sua pergunta para ficar mais fácil de ler

Comment: Valeu Fernando. Recuei 4 espaços e não foi, provavelmente entendi errado e dai abri o <div> para que aparecesse o código, obrigada por ajudar. Usarei o jsFiddle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É o seguinte, se entendi o que você quer. Seu código tem os seguintes problemas:

- Seu seletor do evento `on()` não está preparado para trabalhar com elementos dinâmicos;
- Seu código `html`, ta com uns problemas, tipo tem uns espaços antes das `div`, tipo isso: `< div>< /div>`, e o correto seria `<div></div>` (talvez isso não seja um problema em seu ambiente, mas aqui para mim no Chrome, isso não era interpretado como `html` e sim com `text`);

Então solucionei o problema do seletor do evento `on()`, para elementos dinâmicos assim:

```js
$('.list-mode').on('click', '.img_des_row .icon-trash-med', function(e) {
    $(this).closest(".img_des_row").remove();
});
```

O que acontece e que o método `on()`, funciona da seguinte forma para capturar elementos criados dinamicamente:

Vou tentar explicar por partes:

```js
// o seletor onde o 'on()' é aplicado deve ser um elemento estático, que já exista
// quando a associação do evento seja executado, no caso a 'div' ('.list-mode') 
// onde os elementos dinâmicos serão inseridos.
$('.list-mode')

// o primeiro parâmetro é o evento, no caso o 'click'
// o segundo é o seletor "dinâmico", no caso '.img_des_row .icon-trash-med'
// (eu penso assim: esse seletor secundário será executado a cada evento (no caso click) no seletor (principal('.list-mode')) onde o 'on()' foi aplicado)
// e por ultimo a função de callback do evento (o handler)
.on('click', '.img_des_row .icon-trash-med', function(){...});
```

Não sei se ficou claro minha explicação, qualquer duvida a respeito do método `on()` você pode consultar na [documentação do método `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

E para ficar mas fácil de entender criei um [exemplo da solução funcionando](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/fUDhY/4/)

E se não era bem isso que você necessitava comente.

Comment: Fernando, valeuzão, resolveu meu problema. A div separada era para mostrar o código, porque eu nao estava sabendo inserir direito e dai ele interpretava e só mostrava o texto. Obrigadão.

Comment: @user49915, fico feliz que deu certo e pude lhe ajudar.

Comment: É muito comum esse problema dos eventos não funcionarem em elementos dinâmicos quando se faz uma requisição AJAX. E só com o on() pra resolver isso. @Fernando, foi uma bela explicação!

Comment: Fernando, sua explicação sobre o método On() foi a melhor que encontrei. Eu também estava com o mesmo problema. Mas no meu causo foi apenas uma confusão em relação aos parâmetros que estava passando para o método. Muito obrigado!